# Google Chrome Code Coverage - Removing the unused code

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, code-coverage

I have a hand-me-down WordPress site (passed down from one dev to another, to another, and so on), which is more or less a garbled mess. I'm on the fence between wanting to optimize it and starting fresh. After checking the current state of CSS files with Chrome's Code Coverage, it seems that a lot of the rules (98%, according to the Code Coverage tool) are unused.

Other than testing different resolutions and checking if anything is changing, is there a better (more efficient) way for me to know whether the CSS rules are truly unused? I've been resizing the browser window, and reloading the page (just one out of many), but the number of unused bytes was always the same.